# Java - How to check any file complete downloading in a folder

Tags: java

I need to watch a folder and once there is a file I need to make sure it is complete downloading.Any suggestion?

Comment: We will need some more information - which downloader are you using?  Does the in-progress file have something like .part appended to its name?  Does a file get copied to that folder only when it's done?

Comment: Wondering if file.length() can be use to solve it.

Comment: You would need to know how big the file is expected to be when it's done downloading?  Are you performing the download, or another program?

Comment: Its a .txt file which which drops in to a folder in a server for a .jar file to work on it. It comes from a different server

Comment: Is there anything in the text file that denotes an End Of File, or a way of knowing that it's complete?

Comment: In the future there can be large file coming in to this folder, So I am trying to find a solution to check before .jar comes into play

Comment: How is the other server copying this file?  Is that process under your control?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely vague on implementation details - determining whether a file is 'done' downloading/copying could be done in any number of ways, but requires knowledge of the process.  Having said that, here are some generic but potentially useful options.

If you are not in control of the file being transferred, the following could be used to check whether it is complete:

- Does the filename contain a different extension/suffix (ie, `.part`) while it is busy copying/downloading
- Do you know the expected size of the file
- Do you know the structure of the file, and can you check for an EOF marker

If you are partially in control of the file being transferred (ie, another script, or a call to something like `wget`, etc), you could do the following:

- Wait for an exit code from the script or program doing the transfer
- Have the other program/script rename the file when complete to something you can check for
- Have the other program/script place a text file containing the expected file size in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

When the file shows up, you can fire off a Timer task that checks the file size every second or so. When the file size remains the same over some period of time, the file has stopped transferring.

You need to take in to account your transfer speeds, or any chance of the file stalling. But with modern networks, a few seconds of stability for a basic transfer is more than ample.

Comment: This doesn't provide a way of confirming that the file is complete though - the transfer could've stopped (for any number of reasons) at some arbitrary point.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. But for the arbitrary use case, on modern, reliable networks, it's a practical, and functional heuristic. With more detail, you can get more reliable.

Comment: True. Too little information, and the question seems to have been abandoned for now.  Hope he gets it working, either way. I seem to have gained a serial downvoter for one of my other comments here :p